# IntelliJ maven vs normal maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I would like to add my own commands to delete a specific folder in the mvn repository whenever I run a maven command.

For using maven through the command prompt, this is quite easy since we just update `apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\mvn.cmd` .

However, I noticed that when we run mvn from intelliJ `Maven projects Tool Window`, the command run is the following:

```
    C:\mbakOrg\Oracle\JDK\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=
C:\mbakOrg\_CODE\MNE_ARCHIT_GIT\_REPOS\sg-template-store -Dmaven.home=C:\mbakOrg\build\apache-maven-3.5.3 -
Dclassworlds.conf=C:\mbakOrg\build\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\m2.conf "-javaagent:C:\mbakOrg\devel\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 
2017.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=42633:C:\mbakOrg\devel\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
 C:\mbakOrg\build\apache-maven-3.5.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.3 clean install
```

So how will I add a command that will run every time?
Since maven in `InteliJ`is using a custom way to run maven.

### Explanation

My problem is basically that the mvn -U command does not properly pull the newest code all the time. Additionally, we are all using a snapshot of a parent project that is being updated quite often to fix issues.

Comment: Why do you need to delete a directory in local cache? You simply should use `mvn package` instead of `mvn install`?

Comment: @khmarbaise My problem is basically that the mvn -U command does not properly pull the newest code all the time. Additionally, we are all using a snapshot of a parent project that is being updated quite often to fix issues.

Comment: By `newest code all the time` you mean a project which has been deployed beforehand with the appropriate code ...Are you using dependencies which depend on this code and are you using SNAPSHOT dependencies ? Can you show examples of the pom file you are using and how you are deploying the code to a repository manager ?

Comment: I mean that we have a parent Pom and dependency that is actually hosted as a deployed snapshot on a nexus repository. Another team has lately been making quite a few changes and they unfortunately it is the beginning so they didn’t have a deployed release. Hence, the since it is a snapshot stuff changes and something that was breaking may not break anymore ( as long as the -U flag has pulled the newest stuff). So it happens we say “it don’t work”. They say “use -U”, works for us. And if we delete the cache, it actually does work :(

Comment: Without knowing the details and the poms and how exactly the other people do the deploy via `mvn deploy` and furthermore how you exactly have defined the dependencies in your pom I can't say if there is a problem to solve or not..furthermore `mvn -U clean package` should work without cleaning the local cache...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for the comments. The deploy is taking place to artifactory and actually does work. `mvn -U` should update the local cahe and the files in the m2 repository. I wonder why it would not in some cases. I added however a work-around to manually delete the folder in m2 as a scheduled task so all good . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly discourage modification of `mvn.cmd`. Even if you figure out how to do it in command line, and in InteliJ, then think about moving to some kind of Continuous Integration framework, like Jenkins for example, which will use default `mvn.cmd`?

If there is no possibility to achieve what you want with existing Maven tools, I would recommend writing own Maven plugin, (see [this tutorial](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html)), and put required functionality there. It will guarantee, that this particular piece of code will be executed in all the environments, and this is the way to make sure, that the command will be launched every time.

Comment: My problem is basically that the mvn -U command does not properly pull the newest code all the time. Additionally, we are all using a snapshot of a parent project that is being updated quite often to fix issues.